# GameIcons.get().recolor() always results in a solid black square

Tags: squib

I was following the following tutorial page that describes the game_icons gem package. (stack overflow won't let me post the link along with the two screenshots) I was interested in the recolor options to change one of the images available in the game_icons gem package. Using 
`GameIcons.get().string` works fine but whenever I try to use the `GameIcons.get().recolor().string` I get a solid black square. Here is a test case:

```
require 'squib'
require 'game_icons'

Squib::Deck.new cards: 1 do
  background color: 'pink'
  rect
  # plain GameIcon looks fine
  #svg data: GameIcons.get('glass-heart').string
  # displays a solid black square
  svg data: GameIcons.get('glass-heart').recolor(fg: '333', bg:'ccc').string
  save_png prefix: 'recolor', dir: '.'
end
```

Here is what it looks like without `recolor()`

[GameIcon without recolor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXMRb.png)

Here is what it looks like with `recolor()`

[GameIcon with recolor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBcNG.png)

Does anyone have ideas about what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a `#` in front of the colors.

This should work:

```
require 'squib'
require 'game_icons'

Squib::Deck.new cards: 1 do
  background color: 'pink'
  rect
  # plain GameIcon looks fine
  #svg data: GameIcons.get('glass-heart').string
  # displays a solid black square
  svg data: GameIcons.get('glass-heart').recolor(fg: '#333', bg:'#ccc').string
  save_png prefix: 'recolor', dir: '.'
end
```

To be fair, Squib does this for you so you don't have to remember that part -
 I'll make sure the GameIcons gem does that too.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this when I get home tonight.  FYI the example on the bottom of [this document page](http://squib.readthedocs.io/en/v0.13/guides/game_icons.html) does not have # characters in front of the colors.

Comment: Guilty. I'll fix that - although in this pull request we're making it so you don't have to remember the # sign: https://github.com/andymeneely/game_icons/pull/7

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I swear I thought I had tried it with the # character but apparently I didn't.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to know someone else is using this feature, because I personally love using it.

Comment: Ok as of v0.40 on the gem you no longer need to remember that '#'. Yay!